# Where's my <circle> going?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm looking to create a simple pulsing animation on a `circle` svg element. I'm using a `transform: scale(..,..)` animation but for some reason it's moving the entire circle within its container rather than simply scaling the element itself.

Here's the animation:

```
animation: pulsate 2s infinite linear;

@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

And here's an example (including the same animation applied to a `div` which produces the desired result):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWqVyb

Any ideas on how to create this effect? The circle may be positioned anywhere within the `svg` and it needs to maintain this position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the [`transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) value.

In this case, you would use the value `50% 50%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqoWP)

```
.beacon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #fff;
    animation: pulsate 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

By default, the value is `0 0` on `svg` elements. Reference:

> [**CSS Transforms Module - 8 The transform-origin Property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property)
>
> The default value for SVG elements without associated CSS layout box is `0 0`.

Comment: Great info, I had no idea transform-origin was special for svg

Comment: @aw04 Yeah, I'm not entirely sure *why*. The default value for every other element is `50% 50% 0`.

Comment: The SVG spec (which was defined before the CSS one) has no concept of a transform-origin, and scaling is defined as scaling the entire coordinate system which is a very simple matrix. Melding CSS & SVG together has been an arduous task for the standards guys.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add proper transform-origin to your circle:

```
circle {
  fill: #fff;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
```

transform-origin in HTML has default value `50% 50%;` but not in SVG.